# Creation of Forms having widgets in SmartGWT

Tags: java, gwt, datasource, smartgwt

Thanks guys for your concern as I am tired of by the pathetic support of SmartGWT, however I am pleased to be here as I have got a very positive response here.

My requirement is to create a form that has widgets/controls like button,comboBox and textField on it horizontally but i am getting them vertically. Suggest how can i achieve them vertically.

If i add a HStack on DynamicForm then some of the widgets like comboBox and textBox are not compatible in that situation. Where is the issue lies ?

Comment: did you try reading some documentation?

Comment: Be careful with SmartGWT, it's kind of limited. There are some cute ideas in there, but we raipdly ran out of flexibility especially with things like the DataSource. We ended up switching it out for GXT and there wasn't a single person that had tried SmartGWT that didn't think the switch was a fantastic idea--it's just one of those technolgies that Everyone in the Group is always complaining about--like daily. Their support often comes back with answers that arent helpful as well--like "Our tests all pass so there can be no bug. You are doing something wrong. kthxbye"

Comment: Agree with you Bill.    SmartGWT support is pathetic as well non corporative. I have asked them couple of very basic questions but they didn't even bother to reply them. I mistaken post a thread twice and what I got an rely from SmartGWT support is a threat and be careful not to do so again otherwise you will be ban.

Comment: You have to understand that they are a small team. But you have all you need to make a decision. First, you should start here http://www.smartclient.com/product/competition.jsp to make an opinion about their product. Then you should go here http://www.smartclient.com/releases/SmartGWT_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf and read at least the beginning of the PDF. Once you will be familiar to the concepts, you can browse the online demo here http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/. Please keep in mind, that SmartGWT is an encapsulation of SmartClient. That's the main reason of their non flexibility.

Comment: Thanks Jean for your valuable thoughts on it and i appreciate that.Please share with me possible solution for "My requirement is to create a form that has widgets/controls like button,comboBox and textField on it horizontally but i am getting them vertically. Suggest how can i achieve them vertically.

If i add a HStack on DynamicForm then some of the widgets like comboBox and textBox are not compatible in that situation. Where is the issue lies ?" .

Comment: I want to enter text in textBox and after pressing the add button , it should be added in ComboBox. If data is selected from the ComboBox , it will create a Tab against this event. Please share your valuable suggestion on it

Comment: Something like this    https://cacoo.com/diagrams/y1MeqrvdCp7gMTGN#B61FF

Answer (score 1):

A dynamicform is a sort of grid, by defaul with two columns but you can change this number, every widget is normally filling two cell, one for its title and one for the imput element itself, you can display the title or not, you can change the title oriention (so put it over the input element in place of to the left) etc... you can span a widget on any number of column by using setColspan also.
You can make "holes" in your input widget grid by using spacerItem or even complet row with rowspacerItem.
Many components, many many attributes, many many many work

Comment: I have done the same and got the desired results. I was struggling to put all the controls(two buttons,ComboBox and TextBox).  Now i want somethings like this as

Comment: "Text should be entered in textbox. After pressing the add button , it be added into ComboBox. If the same entry in comboBox selected , it generates a tab against it. "                           Can you help me in this regard

Comment: What do you mean "it generate a tab against it". A combobox is fed via a LinkedHashMap (your java code in the add button will add your entry to this list). You can have a HashSet besides which will avoid you to have duplicate value.

Comment: I want something like as herein : https://cacoo.com/diagrams/y1MeqrvdCp7gMTGN#B61FF    Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You should read the `SmartGWT` Quick Start Guide.

> Smart GWT DataSource objects provide a presentation-independent, implementation-independent description of a set of persistent data fields. DataSources enable you to:
>
> - Share your data models across multiple applications and components, and across both client and server.
> - Display and manipulate persistent data and data-model relationships (such as parent-child) through visual components (such as TreeGrid).
> - Execute standardized data operations (fetch, sort, add, update, remove) with built-in support on both client and server for data typing, validators, paging, unique keys, and more.
> - Leverage automatic behaviors including data loading, caching, filtering, sorting, paging, and validation.
>
> A DataSource descriptor provides the attributes of a set of DataSource fields. DataSource descriptors can be specified in XML format or created in Java code. The XML format is interpreted and shared by both client and server, while DataSources created in Java are used by the client only.

To be more precise, this line is binding a `DataSource` object to a Grid

Comment: For a newbie to SmartGWT , it is difficult to digest such technical details, well for now I have got a good idea from your explanation now.

Answer (score 0):

To have a form with 3 fields horizontally use form.setNumCols(n+1) :

Example:

```
    form.setNumCols(4);
    form.setFields(selectItem, new SpacerItem(), miniDateRangeItem);
```